# WPF Dependency Property Data Binding Problem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

I created a UserControl in WPF.  This user control has several text boxes that are bound to properties on a database object which is referenced by proptery on the UserControl.  The xaml looks like:

```
<TextBox Name="_txtFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=Contact.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

This worked properly until I made the Contact property into a dependency property so that I could bind it to the selected item in a ListBox.  Once I did this the binding of the TextBoxes stopped working.  Why is this?

The DependencyProperty code was:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ContactProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"Contact", typeof(Contacts), typeof(ContactView));
```

Comment: Could you post the DependencyProperty definition as well please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  I forgot to change this code:

```cs
    public Contacts Contact
    {
        get { return _contact; }
        set { _contact = value; }
    }
```

To this:

```cs
    public Contacts Contact
    {
        get { return (Contacts)GetValue(ContactProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContactProperty, value); }
    }
```

Now it works properly.